# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function

Tags: php

It was working but now it stops working why? it soppiest to write into a file and save it. it was working yesterday but today it stops and I can't figure out why a search the internet but still nothing I can't .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact us</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="aboutus.html">About US</a></li>
                <li><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="property.php">Propertys</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<h1>Contact us</h1>

<form  method="post" action="contactus.php" >

    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" required>
    <br>
    <label>Mobile number</label>
    <input type="number" name="number" required>
    <br>
    <textarea name="comments" required></textarea>

    <button name="submit" type="submit"> submit</button>

</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $number = $_POST["number"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];

    $trueemail;

    $massage = $_POST["comments"];

    if(isset($number)){

    if (strlen($number) == 8) {
        $truenumber = true;
    } else {
        echo "Input your mobile number";
    }
}


if(isset($email)){
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Enter a valid email";
    } else {
        $trueemail = true;
    }
}

if($trueemail == true && $truenumber == true){
    writeToFile($email,$number,$massage);

    function writeToFile($trueemail,$truenumber,$massage) {

        $myfile = fopen("contectus.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        fwrite($myfile, $trueemail . PHP_EOL);
        fwrite($myfile, $truenumber . PHP_EOL);
        fwrite($myfile, $massage . PHP_EOL);
        fclose($myfile);
    }
}
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "*Its not working*" isn't very descriptive, and makes it harder for us to help you. Which function is undefined? The `writeToFile()`? We can't magically know that. ;-)

Comment: can you paste what error in detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

1. put submit event starting of the page.
2. you cann't call function without defining before calling.

```
<?php

function writeToFile($trueemail, $truenumber, $massage)
{

  $myfile = fopen("contectus.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
  fwrite($myfile, $trueemail . PHP_EOL);
  fwrite($myfile, $truenumber . PHP_EOL);
  fwrite($myfile, $massage . PHP_EOL);
  fclose($myfile);
}


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $number = $_POST["number"];
  $email = $_POST["email"];

  $trueemail;

  $massage = $_POST["comments"];

  if (isset($number)) {


    if (strlen($number) == 8) {

      $truenumber = true;
    } else {

      echo "Input your mobile number";

    }
  }

  if (isset($email)) {
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      echo "<br>";
      echo "Enter a valid email";
    } else {
      $trueemail = true;
    }
  }

  if ($trueemail == true && $truenumber == true) {
    writeToFile($email, $number, $massage);
  }
} ?>
```

Comment: thanks man it worked Mayne I changed it and didn't know

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `writeToFile($email,$number,$massage);` before you even declare this function.

Move `writeToFile($email,$number,$massage);` after function declaration and your code will works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please put the function outside if condition. something like this

```
function writeToFile($trueemail,$truenumber,$massage)   
    {

            $myfile = fopen("contectus.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
            fwrite($myfile, $trueemail . PHP_EOL);
            fwrite($myfile, $truenumber . PHP_EOL);
            fwrite($myfile, $massage . PHP_EOL);
            fclose($myfile);
    }

if($trueemail == true && $truenumber == true){
    writeToFile($email,$number,$massage);

}
```